# Proximal Operator - Scaling by a Matrix

Tags: convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Proximal operator is defined for matrices as a map prox$_f:R^m\times R^n \rightarrow R^m\times R^n$:

prox$_f$(X) := argmin$_{Y\in R^m\times R^n}$ $ f(Y) + \frac{1}{2}||Y-X||^2$

In case of vectors, it is known http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3522v4.pdf that if $f(x) = \phi(x/p)$, $p \in R, p\ne0$, then prox$_f(x) = p$prox$_{\phi/p^2}(x/p)$.

Is there an alternative when we work with arbitrary matrices, i.e. not necessarily invertible? So for example I have $||PX||_1$, where $P \in R^m\times R^m $, $X \in R^m\times R^n$, and $X$ is a variable. It is known that the proximal mapping for $||X||_1$ is soft-thresholding operator, so I need to 'get rid of' $P$ inside the function.

Comment: Are you sure that you *need* to do this? If you are about to solve a larger optimization problem you may consider the possibility of "dualizing the term with the linear operator" or introducing a new varaible $Y=PX$ and add this equality as a constraint. Both ways make your problem larger but simpler in some sense.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So, correct me if I am wrong: the second option would mean that we would like to solve argmin(W) {||Y||_1 + (1/2)*||W-Y||^2} s.t. Y = P*X. First option, as far as I understand, refers to finding the dual of the function and then using Moreau decomposition (I am not sure at all how to do this).

Comment: What I suspected was, that the proximal operator is not really the object you are interested in. But I may also be wrong...

Comment: I am interested exactly in the proximal operator :) Part of the algorithm.

Comment: In a situation like this, people often resort to using methods like ADMM (or other methods based on Douglas-Rachford), or Chambolle-Pock.

Comment: From what I am reading now, ADMM problem is defined as:
min f(x) + g(z)
s.t. Ax + Bz = c
Would it be legitimate then to have in my case:
min{W} ||Y||_1 + (1/2)*||W-PX||^2
s.t. Y - PX = 0

Comment: That seems like it should be doable, but I'm not sure the optimization problem is stated quite right.  If you'd like you could perhaps open another question asking how to solve your optimization problem with a method like ADMM.

Comment: In your reformulated optimization problem, what exactly are the variables?  I believe $X$ should be listed as a variable.

Comment: No, X in this case is a known matrix. In the original problem of finding prox of ||PX||_1, P was a variable matrix m by m, and X was a known constant matrix m by n. Then I introduce Y=PX, so Y is the second variable now.

Comment: Ah I see.  Perhaps my earlier comments were misleading-- it would be unusual to use a method like ADMM just to evaluate a prox operator.  You probably want this prox operator because you're trying to solve some larger optimization problem.  Whatever that optimization problem is, perhaps ADMM or a similar method would be a good choice.  I would guess that evaluating your prox operator numerically isn't the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this (even if $P$ is invertible), except in some special cases.  If we could, it would make it easy to derive very effective methods for a lot of important convex optimization problems.

One special case where we can do this is when the  matrix $P$ is orthogonal.  To evaluate
\begin{equation*}
\arg \min_x f(Px) + \frac12 \|x - \hat{x} \|^2
\end{equation*}
when $P$ is orthogonal,
we can make the substitution $w = Px$.  Our problem is now to evaluate
\begin{equation*}
\arg \min_w f(w) + \frac12 \|P^T w- \hat{x} \|^2 
= \arg \min_w f(w) + \frac12 \|w - P \hat{x} \|^2.
\end{equation*}
So we need only evaluate the prox operator of $f$.

Another special case is when $f(x) = \frac12 \| x \|^2$, and $P$ is a convolution operator.  In this case the prox operator of $g(x) = f(Px)$ can be evaluated efficiently by setting the derivative equal to $0$ and using the FFT to solve the resulting linear system.